# How to understand this Riak stacktrace?

Tags: riak

Can anyone help me solve this problem, I have the stacktrace of the problem, but can't understand what the trace actually means.

The error occurs when I try to retrieve all data from a bucket, in a Riak Database. And I am using java-riak-client library as the ORM. I can figure out that its a `MapReduce` problem, but other than that.....

Here below is the actual stacktrace, I actually could not figure out what error is it pointing to,
and I tried to find out the record its displaying in error.
@Update: Yes the record is there, when i CURL

```
com.basho.riak.client.RiakException: java.io.IOException: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1>Internal Server Error</h1>The server encountered an error while processing this request:<br><pre>{error,
    {error,
        {case_clause,
            {error,
                {0,
                 [{module,riak_kv_mrc_map},
                  {partition,913438523331814323877303020447676887284957839360},
                  {details,
                      [{fitting,
                           {fitting,<0.21083.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,follow,1}},
                       {name,0},
                       {module,riak_kv_mrc_map},
                       {arg,{{jsfun,<<"Riak.mapValuesJson">>},none}},
                       {output,
                           {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,sink,
                               undefined}},
                       {options,
                           [{log,sink},
                            {trace,[error]},
                            {sink,
                                {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,
                                    sink,undefined}},
                            {sink_type,{fsm,10,infinity}}]},
                       {q_limit,64}]},
                  {type,forward_preflist},
                  {error,[preflist_exhausted]},
                  {input,
                      {ok,{r_object,<<"xxxx-users">>,
                              <<"xxxx@hotmail.com-userpass">>,
                              [{r_content,
                                   {dict,7,16,16,8,80,48,
                                       {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                        [],[],[],[]},
                                       {{[],[],
                                         [[<<"Links">>]],
                                         [],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                         [[<<"content-type">>,97,112,112,108,
                                           105,99,97,116,105,111,110,47,106,
                                           115,111,110],
                                          [<<"X-Riak-VTag">>,54,98,119,73,73,
                                           84,107,120,66,70,107,86,102,67,103,
                                           71,73,116,120,121,85,53]],
                                         [[<<"index">>]],
                                         [],
                                         [[<<"X-Riak-Last-Modified">>|
                                           {1407,514685,380030}]],
                                         [],
                                         [[<<"charset">>,117,116,102,45,56],
                                          [<<"X-Riak-Meta">>]]}}},
                                   <<"{\"identityId\":{\"userId\":\"xxxx@hotmail.com\",\"providerId\":\"userpass\"},\"firstName\":\"xx\",\"lastName\":\"xx\",\"fullName\":\"xx xx\",\"email\":\"xxxx@hotmail.com\",\"authMethod\":{\"method\":\"userPassword\"},\"passwordInfo\":{\"hasher\":\"bcrypt\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$Gm1VVCM09iyI7TQY7r8B7.Baa.YrtHHgREkQpTIH9ThyW4WzuUeJ.\"}}">>}],
                              [{<<35,9,254,249,83,228,76,146>>,
                                {1,63574733885}}],
                              {dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
                                  {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                   [],[]},
                                  {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                    [[clean|true]],
                                    []}}},
                              undefined},
                          undefined}},
                  {modstate,
                      {state,
                          913438523331814323877303020447676887284957839360,
                          {fitting_details,
                              {fitting,<0.21083.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,
                                  follow,1},
                              0,riak_kv_mrc_map,
                              {{jsfun,<<"Riak.mapValuesJson">>},none},
                              {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,sink,
                                  undefined},
                              [{log,sink},
                               {trace,[error]},
                               {sink,
                                   {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,
                                       sink,undefined}},
                               {sink_type,{fsm,10,infinity}}],
                              64},
                          {jsfun,<<"Riak.mapValuesJson">>},
                          none}},
                  {stack,[]}]}}},
        [{riak_kv_wm_mapred,pipe_mapred_nonchunked,3,
             [{file,"src/riak_kv_wm_mapred.erl"},{line,180}]},
         {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,183}]},
         {webmachine_resource,do,3,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,141}]},
         {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,48}]},
         {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,481}]},
         {webmachine_decision_core,handle_request,2,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,33}]},
         {webmachine_mochiweb,loop,1,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_mochiweb.erl"},{line,97}]},
         {mochiweb_http,parse_headers,5,
             [{file,"src/mochiweb_http.erl"},{line,180}]}]}}</pre><P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web server</ADDRESS></body></html>
        at com.basho.riak.client.query.MapReduce.execute(MapReduce.java:81)
        at models.UserRecordsModel$.getAllUsers(UserRecordsModel.scala:131)
        at controllers.DataRetrieval$$anonfun$getRegisteredUserData$1.apply(DataRetrieval.scala:42)
        at controllers.DataRetrieval$$anonfun$getRegisteredUserData$1.apply(DataRetrieval.scala:38)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:221)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:220)
        at securesocial.core.SecureSocial$SecuredActionBuilder$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SecureSocial.scala:117)
        at securesocial.core.SecureSocial$SecuredActionBuilder$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(SecureSocial.scala:113)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at securesocial.core.SecureSocial$SecuredActionBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(SecureSocial.scala:113)
        at securesocial.core.SecureSocial$SecuredActionBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(SecureSocial.scala:112)
        at scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
        at securesocial.core.SecureSocial$SecuredActionBuilder.invokeSecuredBlock(SecureSocial.scala:112)
        at securesocial.core.SecureSocial$SecuredActionBuilder.invokeBlock(SecureSocial.scala:146)
        at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:309)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109)
        at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:108)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4.apply(Action.scala:107)
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:107)
        at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Action.scala:100)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:481)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$mapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:481)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:517)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMapM$1.apply(Iteratee.scala:517)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:493)
        at play.api.libs.iteratee.Iteratee$$anonfun$flatMap$1$$anonfun$apply$13.apply(Iteratee.scala:493)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)
        at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: <html><head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head><body><h1>Internal Server Error</h1>The server encountered an error while processing this request:<br><pre>{error,
    {error,
        {case_clause,
            {error,
                {0,
                 [{module,riak_kv_mrc_map},
                  {partition,913438523331814323877303020447676887284957839360},
                  {details,
                      [{fitting,
                           {fitting,<0.21083.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,follow,1}},
                       {name,0},
                       {module,riak_kv_mrc_map},
                       {arg,{{jsfun,<<"Riak.mapValuesJson">>},none}},
                       {output,
                           {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,sink,
                               undefined}},
                       {options,
                           [{log,sink},
                            {trace,[error]},
                            {sink,
                                {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,
                                    sink,undefined}},
                            {sink_type,{fsm,10,infinity}}]},
                       {q_limit,64}]},
                  {type,forward_preflist},
                  {error,[preflist_exhausted]},
                  {input,
                      {ok,{r_object,<<"xxxx-users">>,
                              <<"xxxx@hotmail.com-userpass">>,
                              [{r_content,
                                   {dict,7,16,16,8,80,48,
                                       {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                        [],[],[],[]},
                                       {{[],[],
                                         [[<<"Links">>]],
                                         [],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                         [[<<"content-type">>,97,112,112,108,
                                           105,99,97,116,105,111,110,47,106,
                                           115,111,110],
                                          [<<"X-Riak-VTag">>,54,98,119,73,73,
                                           84,107,120,66,70,107,86,102,67,103,
                                           71,73,116,120,121,85,53]],
                                         [[<<"index">>]],
                                         [],
                                         [[<<"X-Riak-Last-Modified">>|
                                           {1407,514685,380030}]],
                                         [],
                                         [[<<"charset">>,117,116,102,45,56],
                                          [<<"X-Riak-Meta">>]]}}},
                                   <<"{\"identityId\":{\"userId\":\"xxxx@hotmail.com\",\"providerId\":\"userpass\"},\"firstName\":\"xx\",\"lastName\":\"xx\",\"fullName\":\"xx xx\",\"email\":\"xxxx@hotmail.com\",\"authMethod\":{\"method\":\"userPassword\"},\"passwordInfo\":{\"hasher\":\"bcrypt\",\"password\":\"$2a$10$Gm1VVCM09iyI7TQY7r8B7.Baa.YrtHHgREkQpTIH9ThyW4WzuUeJ.\"}}">>}],
                              [{<<35,9,254,249,83,228,76,146>>,
                                {1,63574733885}}],
                              {dict,1,16,16,8,80,48,
                                  {[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                   [],[]},
                                  {{[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],
                                    [[clean|true]],
                                    []}}},
                              undefined},
                          undefined}},
                  {modstate,
                      {state,
                          913438523331814323877303020447676887284957839360,
                          {fitting_details,
                              {fitting,<0.21083.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,
                                  follow,1},
                              0,riak_kv_mrc_map,
                              {{jsfun,<<"Riak.mapValuesJson">>},none},
                              {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,sink,
                                  undefined},
                              [{log,sink},
                               {trace,[error]},
                               {sink,
                                   {fitting,<0.21081.23>,#Ref<0.0.31.39954>,
                                       sink,undefined}},
                               {sink_type,{fsm,10,infinity}}],
                              64},
                          {jsfun,<<"Riak.mapValuesJson">>},
                          none}},
                  {stack,[]}]}}},
        [{riak_kv_wm_mapred,pipe_mapred_nonchunked,3,
             [{file,"src/riak_kv_wm_mapred.erl"},{line,180}]},
         {webmachine_resource,resource_call,3,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,183}]},
         {webmachine_resource,do,3,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_resource.erl"},{line,141}]},
         {webmachine_decision_core,resource_call,1,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,48}]},
         {webmachine_decision_core,decision,1,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,481}]},
         {webmachine_decision_core,handle_request,2,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_decision_core.erl"},{line,33}]},
         {webmachine_mochiweb,loop,1,
             [{file,"src/webmachine_mochiweb.erl"},{line,97}]},
         {mochiweb_http,parse_headers,5,
             [{file,"src/mochiweb_http.erl"},{line,180}]}]}}</pre><P><HR><ADDRESS>mochiweb+webmachine web server</ADDRESS></body></html>
        at com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.ConversionUtil.convert(ConversionUtil.java:589)
        at com.basho.riak.client.raw.http.HTTPClientAdapter.mapReduce(HTTPClientAdapter.java:386)
        at com.basho.riak.client.query.MapReduce.execute(MapReduce.java:79)
        ... 36 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stack trace is telling us that there was a case clause exception at line 180 of the fie riak_kv_wm_mapred.erl

The clause at that line is handling the responses for the pipe processing the map phase, which appears to be returning the error `preflist_exhausted`, which is not explicitly handled by the case statement.

That error usually indicates that one or more vnodes were overloaded or otherwise unavailable, and fallbacks had not yet started to take over their workload.

The affected partition was `913438523331814323877303020447676887284957839360`, the console.log and error.log may have further details about what happened.

Comment: Well, we have only one node, and all other operations are working just fine without any issues. Just when I try to get all data from a particular bucket I get this error. So, what am I to understand is... riak could not handle extracting all the information from the buckets??

Comment: So now If I am to add another node in the cluster, will that affect the data in the riak db, since I might need to add a node, if my operation are to function properly.

Comment: it would be unusual for a partition to be unavailable to its owning node, did the log files show any errors?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, yes there are error logs and and crash logs, but even they aren't so much readable!!

Comment: OR I have been using `java-riak-client` isn't there a way to retrieve all contents of a bucket without using mapreduce.